# Can't get this sql query works

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data base in mysql, have a Table with name 'campos_personalizados' and a Table with name 'campo_personalizado_envio'.

I need 'envio' with campo_personalizado and valor_campo_personalizado. If campo_personalizado does not match vith value a need a row with null value.

When I execute this query:

```
     select 
 cp.id as id_campo,
 vcp.id as id_valor_campo,
 vcp.valor as valor
 from campo_personalizado cp
 inner join valor_campo_personalizado vcp on cp.id = 
 vcp.id_campo_personalizado
 inner join valor_campo_personalizado_envio vcpe on vcp.id = 
 vcpe.id_valor_campo_personalizado
 where cp.id_encuesta = 1
```

I got this result [Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zxGO.jpg)

But I need something like this:

[Query Result Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R92xT.jpg)

Scripts data base:

```
CREATE TABLE `encuesta` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `envio` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (id_encuesta) REFERENCES encuesta(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `envio_encuestado` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`id_envio` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (id_envio) REFERENCES envio(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `campo_personalizado` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (id_encuesta) REFERENCES encuesta(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `valor_campo_personalizado` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`valor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`id_campo_personalizado` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (id_campo_personalizado) REFERENCES campo_personalizado(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `valor_campo_personalizado_envio` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_valor_campo_personalizado` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_envio` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (id_valor_campo_personalizado) REFERENCES 
valor_campo_personalizado(id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_envio) REFERENCES envio(id)
);

INSERT INTO encuesta (nombre) VALUES('encuesta1');

INSERT INTO envio (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('sin filtros', 1);
INSERT INTO envio (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('valor11', 1);
INSERT INTO envio (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('valor11, valor21', 1);
INSERT INTO envio (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('valor11, valor21, valor31', 1);

INSERT INTO campo_personalizado (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('campo10', 1);
INSERT INTO campo_personalizado (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('campo20', 1);
INSERT INTO campo_personalizado (nombre, id_encuesta) VALUES('campo30', 1);

INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (valor, id_campo_personalizado) VALUES('valor11', 1);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (valor, id_campo_personalizado) VALUES('valor12', 1);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (valor, id_campo_personalizado) VALUES('valor21', 2);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (valor, id_campo_personalizado) VALUES('valor22', 2);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (valor, id_campo_personalizado) VALUES('valor31', 3);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (valor, id_campo_personalizado) VALUES('valor32', 3);

INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (id_valor_campo_personalizado, id_envio) VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (id_valor_campo_personalizado, id_envio) VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (id_valor_campo_personalizado, id_envio) VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (id_valor_campo_personalizado, id_envio) VALUES(1, 4);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (id_valor_campo_personalizado, id_envio) VALUES(3, 4);
INSERT INTO valor_campo_personalizado (id_valor_campo_personalizado, id_envio) VALUES(5, 4);

 --My sql query is
 select 
 cp.id as id_campo,
 vcp.id as id_valor_campo,
 vcp.valor as valor
 from campo_personalizado cp
 inner join valor_campo_personalizado vcp on cp.id = 
 vcp.id_campo_personalizado
 inner join valor_campo_personalizado_envio vcpe on vcp.id = 
 vcpe.id_valor_campo_personalizado
 where cp.id_encuesta = 1
```

Comment: please use text instead of pictures. stackoverflowers will be happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it, query is below

```
select 
consol1.id_encuesta,
consol1.id_envio,
consol1.id_campo,
consol1.nombre_campo,
consol2.valor_campo from
(select 
env.id_encuesta as id_encuesta,
env.id as id_envio,
cp.id as id_campo,
cp.nombre as nombre_campo
from envio env 
inner join campo_personalizado cp on env.id_encuesta = cp.id_encuesta) 
consol1
left join (
select 
env.id as id_envio,
cp.id as id_campo,
vcp.valor as valor_campo
from valor_campo_personalizado_envio vcpe
inner join valor_campo_personalizado vcp on vcp.id = 
vcpe.id_valor_campo_personalizado
inner join envio env on env.id = vcpe.id_envio
inner join campo_personalizado cp on cp.id = vcp.id_campo_personalizado and 
cp.id_encuesta = env.id_encuesta 
) consol2 on consol1.id_envio = consol2.id_envio and consol1.id_campo = 
consol2.id_campo
where consol1.id_encuesta = 1
order by consol1.id_envio asc, consol1.id_campo asc
```

And result query:

```
 id_encuesta    id_envio    id_campo    nombre_campo    valor_campo
 1              1           1           campo10         NULL    
 1              1           2           campo20         NULL    
 1              1           3           campo30         NULL    
 1              2           1           campo10         valor11
 1              2           2           campo20         NULL    
 1              2           3           campo30         NULL    
 1              3           1           campo10         valor11
 1              3           2           campo20         valor21
 1              3           3           campo30         NULL    
 1              4           1           campo10         valor11
 1              4           2           campo20         valor21
 1              4           3           campo30         valor31
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `left join` instead of `inner join` this should do the job

```
select 
 cp.id as id_campo,
 vcp.id as id_valor_campo,
 vcp.valor as valor
 from campo_personalizado cp
 left join valor_campo_personalizado vcp on cp.id = 
 vcp.id_campo_personalizado
 left join valor_campo_personalizado_envio vcpe on vcp.id = 
 vcpe.id_valor_campo_personalizado
 where cp.id_encuesta = 1
```

Comment: Hi, there is not differences. I can't get null values

Answer (score 0):

Try using Left Outer join since you want to fetch all the data from your 
campo_personalizado instead of a Equii Join

```
select 
 cp.id as id_campo,
 vcp.id as id_valor_campo,
 vcp.valor as valor
 from campo_personalizado cp
 Left join valor_campo_personalizado vcp on cp.id = 
 vcp.id_campo_personalizado
 Left join valor_campo_personalizado_envio vcpe on vcp.id = 
 vcpe.id_valor_campo_personalizado
 where cp.id_encuesta = 1
```

Comment: Hi, I get the same result